# The First Fundamental Form (Metric)

Tags: differential-geometry

Compute the First Fundamental Form of the follow parametrized surfaces, where they are regular. If the surface is a ellipsoid such that

$\mathbb{x}(u,v)=(a\sin u\cos v,b\sin u\sin v,c\cos u).$

Hello, is a basic exercise. My teacher wants me to learn how to solve this problem. How me define the First Form is thus...

Let $S$ a surface and let $(U,F,V)$ a parametrization. We have that $g_{ij}: U\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g_{ij}(u)=\left<{\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial v_i}(u),\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial v_j}}(u)\right>.$ Well, according to my calculations, I have to $g_{ij}(u)=\cos(u)\cos(v)\sin(u)\sin(v)(b^2-a^2).$ This is because the partial derivatives are

$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial u}(u)=(a\cos(u)\cos(v),b\cos(u)\sin(v),-c\sin(u))$

$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial v}(u)=(-a\sin(u)\sin(v),b\sin(u)\cos(v),0)$

hence, its follow that the internal product is the number $\cos(u)\cos(v)\sin(u)\sin(v)(b^2-a^2).$ Yes?

Comment: You have found $g_{12}$. Presumably you also need to find $g_{11} = F_{u} \cdot F_{u}$ and $g_{22} = F_{v} \cdot F_{v}$.

Comment: Thanks, but then my solution isn't correct?